# Uniqueness of homomorphism -universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

If $\varphi: R\to A$ is a homomorphism such that for a subset $S$, $\varphi(s)$ is inevertable for every $s\in S$ then there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi^\prime:S^{-1}R\to A$ such that $\varphi = \varphi^{\prime}\circ \pi $. where $\pi:R\to S^{-1}R$ which is defined by: $\pi(r)=\frac{r}{1}$

My problem is to prove the uniqueness of the homomorphism. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: $S$ is a subset of what? What does $S^{-1}R$ mean?

Comment: @ECL my bad, $S$ is a subset of $R$, for $S^{-1}R$ see this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any ring map $ψ \colon S^{-1}R → A$ with $φ=ψ∘π$ and given $r ∈ R$, $s ∈ S$, what is $ψ(\frac r 1)$ mapped to and then what about $ψ(s)ψ(\frac r s)$?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I needed!